# What determines the strength of a tree

Tags: botany

What determines the strength of a tree. A morphologically strong looking tree found broken down at trunk. can we determine the strength/ life of a plant

Comment: Please define what you mean as 'strength' - what aspect are you thinking about?

Comment: I think it is fairy obvious what you are asking (what determines the strength of wood to bending/breaking - probably mainly against horizontal forces), but you should really clarify the Q. However, I think that the Q should be left open until the poster has at least had time to see the comments and rephrase the Q.

Answer (score 1):

I was letting my fingers surfed in the internet about this question and found this interesting article : http://www.caves.org/section/vertical/nh/55/TreeAnchors.pdf 
Your  question is too broad so I guess the link gives a general answer.
hope this helps